# Creating a same-page event with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hyperlink

I am trying to make jquery trigger an event when an anchor link has the same URL as the current page. Eventually this will add a class to the anchor link and let me style it differently with CSS but for now I just want it to show an alert box. Code below doesn't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var buildurl = window.location.href;

if($('a').attr('href') = buildurl){

    alert("Done");

}

});
</script>
```

Can anybody shine a light on why this isn't working? Or a best practice for similar using JQuery?

Link is: http://www.otahboy.com/shop/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4

Cheers,

Jack

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {

var buildurl = window.location.href;

if($('a').attr('href') == buildurl){

    alert("Done");

}

}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. Link is http://www.otahboy.com/shop/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4, just seems determined not to work

Answer (score 0):

use equality operator **`==`**

```
if($('a').attr('href') == buildurl){

    alert("Done");
$('a').attr("color","Red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an assignment in your if condition. You need to add one = to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var buildurl = window.location.href;

if($('a').attr('href') == buildurl){

    alert("Done");

}

});

</script>
```